# Why Azure Container Instance does not have a default HTTPS endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am wondering, what is the reason for Azure Container instances not to have an HTTPS address?
In comparison, Web Apps do have HTTPS endpoint by default, while Container Instances have just HTTP endpoint assigned.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy an application to Azure Web Apps, you are basically running your application behind IIS. You can configure the Web Apps platform to terminate SSL connections and all incoming requests received by your application will be via HTTP.

On Azure Container Instances, you container is directly connected to the network. If you want to terminate SSL before it reaches your application, you would need to have a service which provides SSL termination. The typical way to do this without creating any more infrastructure is to [run nginx as a sidecar to your application container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl).